# Swap for BSC smart contract directly

Tags: python, binance-smart-chain

Hi I am trying to do a swap between two tokens directly from the smart contract using the contract's function 'swap'

https://bscscan.com/address/0x172fcd41e0913e95784454622d1c3724f546f849#writeContract#F10

Here is my code but the transaction failed and not sure why

```html
from web3 import Web3

a_token_0_price = 294.8237179588189932873664394169209
a_token_1_price = 0.003391857367932928995343385329856006

price = math.sqrt(a_token_1_price)
token1_decimals = 18


bsc_endpoint = "https://bsc-dataseed.binance.org/"
web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(bsc_endpoint))
contract_address = '0x172fcd41e0913e95784454622d1c3724f546f849'
checksum_address = web3.to_checksum_address(contract_address)
contract_abi = get_bsc_abi(contract_address)
contract = web3.eth.contract(address=checksum_address, abi=contract_abi)
recipient_address = wallet_address
zero_for_one = True  # Swap token0 for token1 or vice versa
amount_specified = 1000000  
sqrt_price_limit_x96 = int(a_token_1_price * (10 ** token1_decimals))
data = b''  

nonce = web3.eth.get_transaction_count(wallet_address)

tx = contract.functions.swap(recipient_address, zero_for_one, amount_specified, sqrt_price_limit_x96, data).build_transaction({
    'chainId': 56,  # Binance Smart Chain's chain ID
    'gas': 2000000,  # Adjust gas limit accordingly
    'gasPrice': web3.to_wei('5', 'gwei'),  # Adjust gas price accordingly
    'nonce': nonce,
})

# Sign the transaction
signed_tx = web3.eth.account.sign_transaction(tx, private_key)

try:
    # Send the transaction
    tx_hash = web3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_tx.rawTransaction)
    print("Transaction Hash:", web3.to_hex(tx_hash))
except Exception as e:
    print("Transaction failed:", str(e))
```